# Parse heterogenous JSON array

Tags: parsing, json, swift

I need to parse a JSON generated by [iTunes Search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/). I'm looking for all apps by a certain developer, and I usually get a response like this (simplified):

```
{
    "resultCount":4,
    "results": [
                   {
                       "wrapperType":"artist",
                       "artistType":"Software Artist",
                       "artistName":"Vladimir Kelin"
                   },
                   {
                       "wrapperType":"software",
                       "formattedPrice":"Free",
                       "trackId":933241656
                   },
                   {
                       "wrapperType":"software",
                       "formattedPrice":"$1.99",
                       "trackId":1175807581
                   }
                ]
}
```

As you can see, the `results` array is *heterogenous*, meaning it contains objects of 2 different types: `artist` and `software`.

I created a structure, implementing a new handy `Codable` protocol:

```
struct App: Codable {
    let trackId: Int
    let formattedPrice: String?

    /// - Parameter jsonDict: A dictionary produced by JSONSerialization
    init?(jsonDict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let trackId = jsonDict["trackId"] as? Int else { return nil }
        self.trackId = trackId

        formattedPrice = jsonDict["formattedPrice"] as? String
    }
}
```

I don't want to parse `artist` data, so I didn't created any structures for that.

It's relatively easy to parse such JSON using `JSONSerialization`:

```
do {
    let root = try unwrap(JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: receivedData, options: []) as? [String: Any])
    let results = try unwrap(root["results"] as? [[String: Any]])
    var apps = [App]()
    for result in results {
        // Check "software" or "artist"
        guard result["wrapperType"] as? String == "software" else { continue }
        guard let app = App(jsonDict: result) else { continue }
        apps.append(app)
    }
    completion(.ok, apps)
} catch let e {
    let dataStr = String(bytes: receivedData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    print("Exception: \"\(e)\", while parsing data: \"\(dataStr)\"")
    completion(.parseError, nil)
}
```

[*Do you see the `unwrap()` function for the first time?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42696116/3050403)

**The Problem.** I'm looking for a way to parse the response using wonderful [`JSONDecoder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) class introduced in Swift 4. If the `results` array were homogenous I would be able to parse it in just few strings of code.

```
// Helper struct
struct TunesResponse: Codable {
    let resultCount: Int
    let results: [App]
}

// Parsing
let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
if let parsedResponse = jsonDecoder.decode(TunesResponse.self, from: receivedData) {
    let apps = parsedResponse.results
    completion(.ok, apps)
} else {
    completion(.parseError, nil)
}
```

In practice I spend a lot of time but didn't found any way to apply JSONDecoder for such kind of response.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46344963/swift-jsondecode-decoding-arrays-fails-if-single-element-decoding-fails.

Comment: i would like to see how to decode different types with JSONDecoder (like in your example different Objects (`Artist`, `App`) returned depending on the `wrapperType` value

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the models need to be defined, conforming to the *Decodable* protocol. Starting with the base class and then the subclass, see the example below:

```
class FieldDefinition : NSObject, Codable {
    let type: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.type, forKey: .type)
    }
}

class TextFieldDefinition: FieldDefinition {
    let maxLength: Int

    enum TextCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case maxLength
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: TextCodingKeys.self)
        self.maxLength = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .maxLength)
        try super.init(from: decoder)
    }

    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: TextCodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(self.maxLength, forKey: .maxLength)
        try super.encode(to: encoder)
    }
}
```

And here comes the tricky part. Next we create an enum `DemoClassKeys`, which is used to decode the dictionary containing the array of fields.

We also define an enum `FieldDefinitionTypeKey` which is used to serialize the type field (wrapperType in your case) for each object in the array.
And a final enum FieldDefinitionTypes with specifies all the possible FieldDefinition types.

With all the enums specified we can get to the serialization :

```
class DemoClass: Decodable {
    var fieldDefinitions: [FieldDefinition]

    enum DemoClassKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case fieldDefinitions
    }

    enum FieldDefinitionTypeKey: CodingKey {
        case type
    }

    enum FieldDefinitionTypes: String, Decodable {
        case textFieldDefinition = "TextFieldDefinition"
        case deterministicFieldDefinition = "DeterministicFieldDefinition"
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: DemoClassKeys.self)
        var arrayOfFieldType = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: DemoClassKeys.fieldDefinitions)
        var fieldDefinitions = [FieldDefinition]()

        var tmp = arrayOfFieldType
        while(!arrayOfFieldType.isAtEnd) {
            let fieldDefinition = try arrayOfFieldType.nestedContainer(keyedBy: FieldDefinitionTypeKey.self)
            let type = try fieldDefinition.decode(FieldDefinitionTypes.self, forKey: FieldDefinitionTypeKey.type)
            switch type {
            case .textFieldDefinition:
                fieldDefinitions.append(try tmp.decode(TextFieldDefinition.self))
            case .deterministicFieldDefinition:
                fieldDefinitions.append(try tmp.decode(DeterministicFieldDefinition.self))
            }
        }
        self.fieldDefinitions = fieldDefinitions
    }
}
```

And Here is the full working Demo:

```
var json = """
{
    "fieldDefinitions": [
        {
            "type": "TextFieldDefinition",
            "maxLength": 5
        },
        {
            "type": "DeterministicFieldDefinition",
            "defaultValue": "VISA"
        }
    ]
}
"""

let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let results = try jsonDecoder.decode(DemoClass.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    for result in results.fieldDefinitions {
        print(result.self)
    }
} catch {
    print("caught: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the code does not compile: DeterministicFieldDefinition is missing.